# Getting the crash in this library "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar" library in android studio gradle

Tags: android, crashlytics-android

I have added the above crashlytics library in the AndroidStudio project, but its getting the below error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                          Process: com.pw.health.live_patient, PID: 28520
>                                                                                          java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.po.dm.input.DeviceType
>                                                                                              at com.po.sdk.NWFactory.initDeviceInfo(NWFactory.java:293)
>                                                                                              at com.po.sdk.NWFactory.access$500(NWFactory.java:79)
>                                                                                              at com.po.sdk.NWFactory$2.receiveResponseData(NWFactory.java:267)
>                                                                                              at com.po.sdk.http.handler.impl.RequestExecutor.onPostExecute(RequestExecutor.java:128)
>                                                                                              at com.po.sdk.http.handler.impl.RequestExecutor.onPostExecute(RequestExecutor.java:29)
>                                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
>                                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>                                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       12-16 12:37:25.478 28520-28555/com.pw.health.live_patient I/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics report upload complete: 5856754392F0-0001-6F68-9E8808E56C06

Comment: The exception is not caused by Crashlytics.

Answer (score 0):

Refer This it is working fine for me
https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

Comment: Actually I have two applications, one application is working fine,but second application is not working getting the above crash